# Trigger : External Id is not Linking Parent and Child

Tags: trigger, externalid

I am trying to build logic to clone Opportunity and all related Product (Custom) when Opportunity is closed won. I am using externalId to link it. It is cloning opportunity but for it is cloning but linking to Old opportunity not the newly cloned. Am i missing something in logic Can someone please help ?

```
trigger Renewal_Opportunity_trigger on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<opportunity> newopp = new List<opportunity>();
    List<p_product__c> newProd = new List<p_product__c>();
    Set<Id> Ids = new Set<id>();

    for(Opportunity op: trigger.new) {
        if(op.stagename=='Closed Won' && trigger.oldMap.get(Op.Id).stagename !='Closed Won') {
            Ids.add(op.Id);
        }
    }

    for(Opportunity Opp : [Select Id,name,stagename,CloseDate,P_Product_Link__c,(Select name,Opportunity__c from P_Products__r)  from opportunity where Id =: Ids]) {
        if(Opp.P_Products__r.size() > 0) {
            Opportunity CloneOpp = Opp.Clone(false,true,false,false);
            cloneopp.CloseDate=system.today();
            cloneopp.stagename='Prospecting';
            cloneopp.Name=opp.Name+'- Clonned Opp';
            DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
            String dateTimeStr = dt.format('yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss');
            cloneopp.P_Product_Link__c= 'LinkOpp-'+dateTimeStr;
            newopp.add(cloneOpp);
            system.debug('Clonning Opp++'+ newOpp);
            for(P_Product__c prod:opp.p_products__r) {
                P_Product__c pro = prod.clone(false,true,false,false);
                prod.Opportunity__r  = new Opportunity(P_Product_Link__c= cloneopp.P_Product_Link__c); 
                //prod.Opportunity__r = OppReference;
                pro.name=prod.name+'-'+'Clonned Pord';
                newprod.add(pro);
                system.debug('Clonning Prod++'+ newProd);
            }
        }
    }

    If(newopp.size() > 0 && newprod.size() > 0) {

        insert newOpp;
        upsert newprod;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you made a typo here:
`prod.Opportunity__r  = new Opportunity(P_Product_Link__c= newopp.P_Product_Link__c);`
`prod` is your source object to be cloned from.
It should be `pro.Opportunity__r`.

Comment: Thank you Hengky, good catch :) After changing it start with another error.  - Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference Opportunity__r and a salesforce id, Opportunity__c: []

Comment: You need to remove the Opportunity lookup reference in the child query because it is getting cloned into your new product record. You don't need the field since you are setting it via external id field.

Comment: @HengkyIlawan that won't work, setting the lookup reference to null still counts as specifying both it and the external id reference.

Comment: @EranV, I am not saying to nullify the opportunity lookup field, I am saying to omit the Opportunity field from the child query.

Comment: Thanks Eran v @HengkyIlawan :  I removed but still same error. I am not sure removing/adding Opportunity from query will cause issue. (Select name from P_Products__r )

Comment: Finally after so much debugging and reading i found issue. We can not use Clone when inserting child as it will always bring master record Id and upsert will fail. P_Product__c pro = prod.clone(false,true,false,false); > does not work because it always bring Opportunity Id. We need set value for all field for child record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting Answer for my question it may save your time if you facing same issue or looking similar solution.

External Id does magic when we want to insert Parent Child in same transaction -

Here is working code

```
trigger Renewal_Opportunity_trigger on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<opportunity> newopp = new List<opportunity>();
    List<p_product__c> newProd = new List<p_product__c>();
    Set<Id> Ids = new Set<id>();

    for(Opportunity op: trigger.new) {
        if(op.stagename=='Closed Won' && trigger.oldMap.get(Op.Id).stagename !='Closed Won') {
            Ids.add(op.Id);
        }
    }

    for(Opportunity Opp : [Select Id,name,stagename,CloseDate,P_Product_Link__c,(Select name,Opportunity__c from P_Products__r)  from opportunity where Id =: Ids]) {
        if(Opp.P_Products__r.size() > 0) {
            Opportunity CloneOpp = Opp.Clone(false,true,false,false);
            cloneopp.CloseDate=system.today();
            cloneopp.stagename='Prospecting';
            cloneopp.Name=opp.Name+'- Clonned Opp';
            DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
            String dateTimeStr = dt.format('yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss');
            cloneopp.P_Product_Link__c= 'LinkOpp-'+dateTimeStr;
            newopp.add(cloneOpp);
            system.debug('Clonning Opp++'+ newOpp);
            for(P_Product__c prod:opp.p_products__r) {
                //P_Product__c pro = prod.clone(false,true,false,false); > does not work because it always bring master record Id field
                prod.Opportunity__r  = new Opportunity(P_Product_Link__c= cloneopp.P_Product_Link__c); 
                pro.name=prod.name+'-'+'Clonned Pord';
                newprod.add(pro);
                system.debug('Clonning Prod++'+ newProd);
            }
        }
    }

    If(newopp.size() > 0 && newprod.size() > 0) {

        insert newOpp;
        upsert newprod;
    }
}
```